# How to get the most recent compilation time and date of the current source file in Golang?

Tags: go

This code returns the most recent compilation time and date  of the current source file:

```golang
package main

/*
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>
void getCompileDateTime(uint8_t  dt[12],uint8_t tm[9]){
  strcpy(dt, __DATE__); //Mmm dd yyyy
  strcpy(tm,__TIME__);  //hh:mm:ss
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    dt := make([]byte, 12)
    tm := make([]byte, 10)
    C.getCompileDateTime((*C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&dt[0])), (*C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&tm[0])))
    dts, tms := string(dt), string(tm)
    fmt.Println(dts, tms)
}
```

Is there pure Golang way to this or this is the only way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found another method of using an option on the [go linker](https://golang.org/cmd/link/) to assign a string:

> -X importpath.name=value
>
> Set the value of the string variable in importpath named name to value.
>       Note that before Go 1.5 this option took two separate arguments.
>       Now it takes one argument split on the first = sign.

Code sample:

```
package main

import "fmt"

var compileDate string

func main() {
   fmt.Println(compileDate )
}
```

When building:

```
go build -ldflags "-X main.compileDate=`date -u +.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S`" main.go
```

The advantage of this method, is it can be more OS agnostic through build scripts without littering your code with `go:generate`

Answer (score 1):

It is not the compilation time but the executable modification time what is nearly the same during development time. Of course it can get faulty when the executable is copied but may be it helps someone:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

var (
    linkTime string
)

func main() {
    fi, _ := os.Stat(os.Args[0])
    linkTime = fi.ModTime().String()
    fmt.Println(linkTime)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EH1B9NBnqQB)

Answer (score 0):

Use go:generate. As part of your build process you'll have to run `go generate` prior to running your program. You can encapsulate this in a shared function to use across files.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strconv"
    "time"
    "strings"
)

//go:generate sh -c "date +'%s' > main_timestamp.go.txt"

func main() {
    txt, err := ioutil.ReadFile("main_timestamp.go.txt")
    if err == nil {
        i, err := strconv.ParseInt(strings.TrimSpace(string(txt)), 10, 64)
        if err == nil {
            t := time.Unix(i, 0)
            fmt.Printf("%s", t)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("error parsing file %s", err)
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("error reading file %s", err)
    }
}
```